# I have a 64 bit Ubuntu12.04 PC. I want to install VLC player without useing Internet?

Tags: 12.04

I have a 64 bit Ubuntu12.04 PC. I want to install VLC player without using Internet?Please suggest as I dont have Internet available on ubuntu PC

Comment: VLC usually has a bunch of dependencies, so you'll probably need to try hard :) If you have another machine with internet connection and with the exact same version of Ubuntu, you can try to install VLC on that machine, then copy the entire `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory across to the disconnected machine and try to install it there. This idea is explored in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory

Comment: Besides muru's dupe: have someone send you the source files for vlc through snail mail. Mind though: Ubuntu is an operating system that has a high demand for an internet connection. Not permanent but the installation and updating of software surely do.

Answer (score 0):

Get VLC packages from this site. 
http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/vlc_2.0.1-4_amd64.deb.html
Download all the dependent libraries as well. 
Make two directories. vlc and lib.

Install all .debs from lib first dpkg -i *.deb

Then install vlc's deb.

Comment: -1 Do you read the questions before you answer? !!! "I dont have Internet available on ubuntu PC"

Comment: Cant you access internet in this world. I am not sure which country you are from, But we have many friends with internet or cyber cafe where we can access internet.

Comment: I have Internet, but OP not: "I dont have Internet available on ubuntu PC" Read the question.

Comment: @A.B. the OP obviously has access to the internet, else they wouldn't have posted this question on an online forum. They just can't access it from Ubuntu. However, downloading the relevant .deb files and their dependencies will let them install offline.